# Solving logcat warning messages in android studio

Tags: android, android-activity, android-logcat

```
09-26 11:16:08.447    7297-7297/com.top.myapp W/asset﹕ AssetManager-->
addDefaultAssets CIP path not exist!
```

How can i solve the above warning message shown in logcat while debugging my android app? Since it does not even indicate  the line where the issue was found in my app. Please share some reference documents.

Comment: in your asset folder any image ya file has Capital latter name .. check your asset folder

Comment: @Destro am using ubuntu 15.04. how can i locate the assert folder?

Comment: @Destro seems like there is nothing in my assert folder